# Not able to record script with open script version 12.5 on firefox version 3.6.10

Tags: firefox, record, openscript

I am trying to record a script in openscript on firefox browser but only browser.launch is recorded other steps are not recorded.

I have firefox version: 3.6.10
open script version: 12.5
Openscript addon for firefox is enabled : OpenScript WebDOM 2.0
I have xpinstall.signatures.require is set 'false'

Java version m using is 1.8

Tried to restart openscript with admin rights
Tried to reboot my system

But still not able to record the script. I can't record script on IE as my application doesn't work on IE.

Thanks in advance for help!!

Answer (score 0):

OpenScript version is too old, also nobody is using such old firefox version 
pls use latest version.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/index-084446.html